# How to configure Apache Ranger UI admin username and password?

Tags: apache-ranger

I am doing the command-line installation of Apache Ranger i.e. without Ambari.
I have to configure Ranger UI username and password other than the defaults (i.e. admin/admin). Does anyone know which configuration file and what properties need to be set to do that?

Comment: You can change the defaults in the settings from the UI once the implementation is complete, is it not simple?

Comment: I guess I am looking for a way to configure before implementation.